# How to prevent error when rotating device while RSS feed loads

Tags: android, rotation, rss, rss-reader

I have developed a small app that reads and rss xml file from my own link. The application runs fine.

However, I have noticed that when I rotate the phone before the feed loads completely the application crashes.

Also if I rotate the device after the RSS feed loads,  the Activity reloads the feed again. Anyone know what or why the crash happens?

I was thinking of the following 2 solutions:

- Force the Activity to be in portrait layout all the time.
- Disable the rotation while the RSS feed loads and then release after. If that is at all possible.

Any suggestions?

Sorry for a delay... the following is the trace i got:

09-15 09:53:31.209 30468-30468/com.rrrrrrrr.xxxxxxxxxx E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
09-15 09:53:31.754 30468-30468/com.rrrrrrrr.xxxxxxxxxx E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
09-15 09:53:31.769 30468-30468/com.rrrrrrrr.xxxxxxxxxx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-15 09:53:31.769 30468-30468/com.rrrrrrrr.xxxxxxxxxx E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.relentlessdev.maleadvise, PID: 30468
09-15 09:53:31.769 30468-30468/com.rrrrrrrr.xxxxxxxxxx E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{78a8658 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-1696,464} not attached to window manager

Comment: Maybe solution 3: fix the bug in your code that makes your app crash when you rotate the device? Unless you post some code and the stack trace nobody will be able to help you with that though.

Comment: The code has no issues but I will provide the trace later on when I can connect to the PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I can think (As you have not provided any code snippet) of is that you are missing very important point related to android activity. Activity in android is created again from scratch whenever screen rotation changes. Most probably there is some NullPointerException in your code when activity is created again. There are couple of methods to handle screen rotation in android at activity level. The best solution according to me would be to override

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
```

for Activity class and handle the rotation yourself.

Comment: Oh ok... I did not know that the Activity is recreated. I will look into it and see how to handle that. Most likely in this case the adapter for the list is throwing an exception. I will try again later today.

Answer (score 0):

Android kills your activity when the phone is rotated. OnCreate is called each time the phone is rotated. The reason for the exception is your views are dependent on variables that have not been initialized.

So, you need to save the feed data to the bundle in OnSaveInstanceState and retrieve it in OnRestoreInstanceState. In your OnCreate method, check if the bundle passed to it is null. If it is null, then the activity has been started for the first time and you need to load feed data from the XML - initialize your variables. If it is not null, then the phone had been rotated and you can simply reload the feed data from the bundle - initialize your variables from the data restored from the bundle.